# can't print a string value after copy in c++

Tags: c++, string

```
string s1 = "Hello";
string s2;
copy(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin());
cout << s2 << endl;
```

This piece of code looks simple but it prints nothing at the last line. Can someone tell me what's problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The destination string has no size. Try using `std::back_inserter()`:

```
copy(s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter(s2));
```

Comment: Is there a way to new the string s2 with a size?

Comment: @canoe You could do something along the lines of `string s2(s1.size(), ' ')`, but that just seems really redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to copy into the content of `s2`, but it's empty, so that produces undefined behavior.

Try something like:

```
copy(s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter(s2));
```

...or:

```
s2.assign(s1);
```

...or the cleanest and most obvious:

```
s2 = s1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to copy the string `s1` to `s2`, just pass `s1` to the constructor of `s2`:

```
string s1 = "Hello";
string s2(s1);
cout << s2 << endl;
```